# How to make the whole content of the page automatically adjust when resized

Tags: html, css

**My goal** is to create a website where the bg is auto-adjusted to the center, with my text on the blue area

Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Minecraft</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="My Name">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap');
    .Gaming {
      font-family: 'Lora', serif;
      color: red;
    }
    
    .border {
      background-color: white;
      margin: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
      border: 5px solid;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      /* background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530305408560-82d13781b33a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80); */
    }
    
    .ave {
      width: 25%;
      height: 50;
    }
    
    .app {
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
    }
    
    .minecraftbody {
      background-image: url(https://www.startpage.com/av/proxy-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwallpaper-house.com%2Fdata%2Fout%2F8%2Fwallpaper2you_213216.jpg&sp=1637611406T358bfd9113b26feaf1742f91b1f8cc55007334c10b4ecebee265c9435d20b5f9);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto;
    }
    
    .homebg {
      background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo--82d13781b33a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80);
      background-size: auto;
    }
    
    .mchead {
      color: white;
      left: 90px;
      top: 26px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
    }
    
    .mcp {
      color: black;
      border: 5px solid;
      position: relative;
      left: 500px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body class='minecraftbody'>

  <h1 class="mchead">MINECRAFT</h1>

  <div class="mcp">

    <p>Minecraft is one of my favorite games ever since I was still a child. I made many friends through it and <br> countless memories was and are being made.
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>

    <p>This is a picture of one of my servers that me and my friends made in Minecraft. <br> We had so much fun making this house and I still come back to this place everytime I feel nostalgic <br> about my past</p>

    <img src="Images/Mc_server.png" alt="minecraft server">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can see that the background is not resized properly in the window. And there seems to be a line that extends to infinity when zoomed out. Any way to fix this?

Comment: If you want to size things based on the window size, you can use VH and VW units https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood that is, that you want your bg image to be centered, is that right? If yes, try to give the background image a `background-position: center` attribute. Let me know, if I got that correct. Cheers